# Jquery .on() not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have the following:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Inside of jQuery I have have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").on("click", function () { 
        alert('test');
    });
});
</script>
```

This doesn't work. I am using IE9.

Might anybody know which version of Jquery is supporting `.on()`?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of IE? Also, is `#submit` dynamically generated?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting any errors? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but are you loading jQuery? And if so, what version? .on() is somewhat newer.

Comment: [it works as long as you've got jQuery loaded](http://jsfiddle.net/wS4xC/).

Comment: Are you using the right version of jQuery.  `on` was not in older versions.

Comment: it's working in IE9 on my test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this version of `on`

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on("click","#submit", function (e) { 
    //e.preventDefault();  // if you want to prevent default form submission
     alert('test');
   });
});
```

Comment: tnx, it was a life saver. IE should really DIE!

Answer (score 2):

make sure you load `jQuery.js` then try:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
   alert("test");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following alternates:

```
 $('#submit').bind('click', function() {
  alert('Test');
});
```

OR

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
   alert("Test");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't do well when using 'reserved' names as element's ID.

See this fiddle, your code works great if you change the ID of the input to something different than '#submit'

http://jsfiddle.net/6yAuz/3/

Comment: @Rocket - this works for me as well!!. I think I may be on an older version of Jquery. Which version is it supported on?

Comment: @NatePet: The lastest version of jQuery is 1.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the 'submit' element you are referring to actually exists at document load. If you are creating it dynamically, the 'on' function will have nothing to bind it to.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this using when using IE9 in compatibility mode. Note, I had no problem when using IE9 in regular mode.

I was able to do a more thorough QA for a site I just launched (time didn't permit much cross-browser testing beyond using a screenshot service). Changing $("something").on("click"...) to $("something").click() fixed the issue.

Comment: So this is basically the same as [*mgraph*'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11439239/1715579)?

Comment: I gave a specific example of where it doesn't work, as the other way does work in modern browsers.